# InetSocketAddress throws Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ConnectionFactory.class, Proxy.class})
public class ConnectionFactoryTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Mock
    private Proxy proxy;

    @Mock
    private InetSocketAddress inetSocketAddress;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Proxy.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(InetSocketAddress.class).withArguments(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyInt()).thenReturn(inetSocketAddress);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(Proxy.class).withArguments(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, Mockito.any(InetSocketAddress.class)).thenReturn(proxy);
    }

    @Test
    public void testInitializeProxy() throws Exception {
        connectionFactory.getHttpURLConnection(Mockito.any(URL.class));
    }
}

public class ConnectionFactory implements HttpURLConnectionFactory {

    private String proxyHost;

    private Integer proxyPort;

    Proxy proxy;

    public HttpURLConnection getHttpURLConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
        InetSocketAddress inetSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort); // error occurs here
        proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, inetSocketAddress);
        return (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
    }
}
```

While running the testcase, `new InetSocketAddress` is invoked with `anyString()` and `anyInt()` but still throws `NullPointerException`. Any suggestions would be welcome in this regard.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.impl.ConnectionFactory.getHttpURLConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:10)
at com.impl.ConnectionFactoryTest.testInitializeProxy(ConnectionFactoryTest.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:316)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:300)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:288)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:208)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:121)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:123)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:121)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Error Trace is added above. This error occured while executing the test method testInitializeProxy() in ConnectionFactoryTest class

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: InetSocketAddress inetSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort); When executing this line, I am getting null pointer exception. Above is the setUp() written for this

Comment: You might want to update your question to include that!

Comment: Updated the question with additional classes

Comment: Is the NullPointerException coming from the Strings proxyHost , proxyPort ? Are you sure it is the InetSocketAddress?

Comment: @Sethuraman Please include the full error stack trace and error message from the exception to your question. Also, add a comment at the end of the mentioned line from the exception in your source code so we can see the location where there error occured.

Comment: proxyHost & proxyPort will anyways be null when running a test case, and thats the reason I wrote in setUp() method mocking those values to return a mocked InetSocketAddress.

Comment: The stack trace doesn't correspond to the line you marked as "// error occurs here". It must be somewhere else, or you are running a class file that is out of date compared to your latest source.

Comment: I removed all the imports and hence the line numbers didnt match. May be I can change the line number in stack trace to match that

Comment: Looks like it's the `url` that is null

Comment: When I debug, debugger stops in InetSocketAddress line and immediately after that, I get Null Pointer Exception. So even if url is null, atleast I should get mocked InetSocketAddress before executing null URL, if I am not wrong

Comment: Both Maurice Perry and I think that the problem is *not* at the line where you call `new InetSocketAddress`. If you pass null to the `InetSocketAddress` constructor you get an IllegalArgumentException and a stack trace that includes the InetSocketAddress class. You are not getting such a stack trace. You are getting a NullPointerException *directly* in your `getHttpURLConnection` method. That is where the NPE occurs. Looking at the body of that method, the *only* place where NPE can be thrown is the line `url.openConnection` when url is null. Unless what you show is not what you run.

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding your project.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException If u see my above comment, even if the url object throws NPE, I should get mocked InetSocketAddress & mocked Proxy object as per the setUp() method. Am I right ? But NPE occured in the line where new InetSocketAddress is created. I got this while debugging this test case.

Comment: @Sethuraman Not sure if relevant, but you only use `Proxy.class` in your mock setup, not `InetSocketAddress.class` (for the `@PrepareForTest` annotation and `PowerMockito.mockStatic()` call).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized `proxyHost`.

So that member variable is `null` until you actually initialize it.

Comment: But I get Null Pointer before executing the code related to Proxy. And moreover code is working fine for proper data. Wanted to write related test case for this code execution